# Get pixel size of raster in meters when unit of CRS is not in meters

Tags: coordinate-system, rasterio

I have a raster that I read with `rasterio`

```
dataset = rasterio.open(f'{PATH}.tif')
```

The CRS is

> epsg:4326

I want to know the pixel size of my raster. From the [doc](https://rasterio.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api/rasterio.io.html#rasterio.io.DatasetWriter.res) I know that `res` returns the (width, height) of pixels in the units of its coordinate reference system.

```
pixel_size_x, pixel_size_y = dataset.res
```

> 9.989276315832508e-07
> 9.972246695723605e-07

After googling I know that degrees is my unit. How can I express my pixel size in meters? If possible I want to prevent reprojecting the raster.

Comment: There is no exact conversion to meters from 4326 degrees. Neither the X nor Y dimension is fixed in planar units. Only an equal area projection has a hope of having uniform dimensions (and will require resampling to accomplish the conversion (affecting data quality).

Comment: If you assume a spherical earth model (instead of an ellipsoidal one) you can get a fairly good estimate by scaling according to some trigonometric function of the latitude (1 degree square at the equator is bigger than 1 degree square at the poles). A little more complexity can probably do it more precisely for the WGS84 ellipsoid model. Am pretty sure its been done, have a search and see what you can find.